# How can i successfully use UNICODE characters in my .py files without causing trouble?

Tags: python, unicode

I am writing a test for a database which has Swedish characters in it. In the test, i directly use characters with umlauts and other such Swedish ligatures and it runs just fine, reading filenames in from a database and doing string compares successfully.

However, upon importing this file to do pydoc generation, i get the all-too-familiar exception:

> SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file foo.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details

Upon doing some investigation on my own, i found that adding

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*-
```

to the top of my file fixed the importing problem. However, now the test fails all of the string comparisons. I tried the alternate method of forgoing the coding declaration and writing the strings as

```
u"Bokmärken"
```

... but this still doesn't keep the test from failing.

Does anyone know a good way to fix this?

Comment: if the string comparison is failing, print out the strings with repr(string) and see why. probably a character set mismatch. if you'll post some code, it'll be easier for people to help.

Comment: Slightly random: I don't know any Swedish, but does "Bokmärken" mean "Bookmarks"?

Comment: @JAB do you assume that python hates to print out some specific words, or dislikes sweden?:) Or this information really can be somewhat related to the question?

Comment: It may be, that file itself is saved in the wrong encoding, and this cause troubles. Being russian, I face this issue too often.

Comment: so, we need a code to investigate what has gone wrong. Codepage of script file itself, database's client codepage or data, or 'str' instead of 'unicode' in sql result set or some other problem among the big set of ones related to Codepage Hell.

Comment: @Max: That's why it's random.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to set your encoding in your editor and the database so that they match. If your database is utf-8 encoded, and not iso-8859-15, then setting your editor to utf-8 should fix it. However, since your u'string' comparisons fail, this might not be the case.

Replace

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*-
```

with

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

or (the equivalent)

```
# coding=utf-8
```

To try utf-8 encoding.

Printing debugging output with `repr('swedish string'` and `repr(u'swedish string')` will also be useful in inspecting differences.
Right after your interpreter line. Can you tell us what encoding your database is set to? Additionally, was the database data written by python or inserted directly? You could have written data in the wrong encoding to the database to begin with, which is now causing problems on comparison.

Comment: @Blackmoon, right. I've added a note about that in case their editor is not set up in such a way.

Comment: This fixed it completely! I could have sworn the database was written in ISO-8859-15, but that assumption was apparently off-base. Thank you so much.